# bash script pass a variable to a ./configure command containing quotes and expansion

Tags: bash, quotes

I ham having difficulty understanding how to pass a variable to a ./configure command that includes variable expansion and quotes.

myvars.cfg

```
myFolderA="/home/myPrefix"
myFolderB="/home/stuffB"
myFolderC="/home/stuffC"
optsA="--prefix=${myFolderA}"
optsB="CPPFLAGS=\"-I${myFolderB} -I${myFolderC}\""
cmd="/home/prog/"
```

myScript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
. /home/myvars.cfg
doCmd=("$cmd/configure" "${optsA}" "${optsB}")
${doCmd[@]}
```

The `doCmd` should look like this

```
/home/prog/configure --prefix=/home/myPrefix CPPFLAGS="-I/home/stuffB -I/home/stuffC"
```

however it seems when running bash it is adding single quotes

```
 /home/prog/configure --prefix=/home/myPrefix 'CPPFLAGS="-I/home/stuffB' '-I/home/stuffC"'
```

causing an error of

```
configure: error: unrecognized option: `-I/home/stuffC"'
```

Is there a way to pass a variable that needs top be expanded and contains double quotes?

Comment: It works fine for me.  There was a double quote missing in your code and I edited your question.

Answer (score 1):

As your script is written, there is no point to using the `doCmd` array. You could simply write the command:

```
"$cmd/configure" "${optsA}" "${optsB}"
```

Or, more simply:

```
"$cmd/configure" "$optsA" "$optsB"
```

However, it is possible that you've simplified the script in a way which hides the need for the array. In any case, if you use the array, you need to ensure that its elements are not word-split and filepath expanded, so you must quote its expansion:

```
"${doCmd[@]}"
```

Also, you need to get rid of the quotes in `optsB`. You don't want to pass

```
CPPFLAGS="-I/home/stuffB -I/home/stuffC"
```

to the `configure` script. You want to pass what the shell would pass if you typed the above string. And what the shell would pass would be a single command-line argument with a space in it, looking like this:

```
CPPFLAGS=-I/home/stuffB -I/home/stuffC
```

In order to get that into `optsB`, you just write:

```
optsB="CPPFLAGS=-I${myFolderB} -I${myFolderC}"
```

Finally, the shell is not "adding single quotes" into the command line. It is showing you a form of the command whch you could type at the command-line. Since the argument (incorrectly) contains a quote symbol, the shell shows you the command with its arguments skingle-quoted, so that you can see that the optB has been (incorrectly) split into two arguments, each of which contains (incorrectly) one double quote.

You could have found much of the above and more by pasting your script into https://shellcheck.net. As the [bash tag summary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash)  suggests, you should always try that before asking a shell question here because a lot of the time, it will solve your problem instantly.

Comment: Excellent answer, very nicely explained.